# Train on colab TPU without data from GCP, for data that can be all loaded into memory

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tpu

From the official TPU documentation, it says that train files must be on GCP

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting#cannot_use_local_filesystem

But I have a smaller dataset (but the training would take a very long time due to the training being based on sampling/permutations) which can be all loaded into memory (1-2 gb). I am wondering if I can somehow just transfer the data objects to the TPU directly, and it can use that to train the files.

If it makes a difference, I am using Keras to do my TPU training.

What I looked at so far:

It seems that you can loaded certain data onto individual TPU cores

```
self.workers = ['/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:' + str(i) for i in range(num_tpu_cores)]

with tf.device(worker[0):
    vecs = vectors[i]
```

However, I am not sure if this would translate into coordinated training among all the TPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

You can read files with Python:

```
with open(image_path, "rb") as local_file:
  img = local_file.read()
```

1-2 GB may be too big for TPU. If you are out of memory - split your data to smaller portions.